Strong convergence of a sequence in $L^2((0,T); H^{s,2}(\Omega)) \cap C([0,T];H^{-s,2}(\Omega))$, $0<s<1$
Let $u_n$ be a sequence with $u_n \in L^2((0,T);H^{1,2}(\Omega))$ and $\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial t} \in L^2((0,T);H^{1,2}(\Omega)^*)$. Then, how could one get a subsequence of $u_n$ that strongly converges in  $L^2((0,T); H^{s,2}(\Omega)) \cap C([0,T];H^{-s,2}(\Omega))$, where $0<s<1$?
My attempt: $H^{1,2}(\Omega)$ compactly embedded in $H^{s,2}(\Omega)$ and $H^{s,2}$ is continuously embedded in $H^{1,2}(\Omega)^*$. Then by Aubin-Lions lemma, existence of a strongly convergent subsequence can be founded in $L^2((0,T); H^{s,2}(\Omega))$. But I can't do the rest part.

The second compact inclusion also follows from an Aubin-Lions type result. There is for example the famous paper Compact sets in $L^p$ by Simon (it usually ranks high on most-cited-per-year lists) which gives a lot of results of this type.
You can use it as follows, relying on boundedness in a space compactly included in $H^{-s,2}(\Omega)$, which is going to be $L^2(\Omega)$, and some regularity for translations in time in a weaker space, which is going to be $H^{1,2}(\Omega)^*$. (I assume you mean $H^{-s,2}(\Omega) = H^{s,2}(\Omega)^*$.)
It is a standard result (e.g. in Dautray/Lions, Mathematical Analysis and Numerical Methods for Science and Technology, Volume 5, Chapter XVIII) that $$W^{1,2}(0,T;H^{1,2}(\Omega)^*) \cap L^2(0,T;H^{1,2}(\Omega)) \subseteq C([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$$ with continuous inclusion. Moreover (fundamental theorem of calculus),
$$W^{1,2}(0,T;H^{1,2}(\Omega)^*) \subseteq C^{1/2}([0,T];H^{1,2}(\Omega)^*),$$ this is the desired regularity in time,
and  $$L^2(\Omega) \subseteq H^{-s,2}(\Omega) = H^{s,2}(\Omega)^* \subseteq H^{1,2}(\Omega)^*$$
with compact inclusions for any $0 < s < 1$. Thus you can use Theorem 5 in the paper of Simon which gives you compactness of the inclusion
$$W^{1,2}(0,T;H^{1,2}(\Omega)^*) \cap L^2(0,T;H^{1,2}(\Omega)) \subseteq C([0,T];H^{-s,2}(\Omega)).$$

What is the difference between $W^{1,2}$ and $H^{1,2}$?

@AlexM. in this case, none, OP used $H$ for the spatial Sobolev spaces, which I kept, and then I also used $W$ for the Bochner-Sobolev space. I have rarely seen the latter been called $H$, though.
